# What is the difference between class methods and instance methods [sequelize]

Tags: database, node.js, sequelize.js

Sequelize allows you to add custom methods to a [model](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/docs/models/#expansion-of-models), and there are two ways to do so:

- classMethods: {}
- instanceMethods: {}

In Sequelize I can't find an explanation about the differences of this two objects. Could anyone explain the difference with an example when to use one or the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class is the object you get when you call `sequelize.define`. It stands for the whole table.

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {...});
```

Instance is like one unit of that class, i.e. a row in the collection's table:

```
User.create({}).then(function(user) {
  // `user` is an instance.
});
```

Class methods are functions that don't expect an instance. You can call those like this:

```
User.myMethod();
```

Instance methods are ones that operate on a single instance. You can call them like this:

```
user.myMethod();
```

`this` in class methods is a class. `this` in instance methods is an instance (obviously).